# Username for Windows Server Nano Recovery Console

Tags: windows-server-2016

I've loaded up a new Nano VM but, at the recovery console, I'm prompted to enter a username, password and domain.

I'm not attached to a domain and I know the password I created with the PS scripts, but what is the user name?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It's Administrator...

All this time I was misspelling it.